# python mysql library not establish connection with ssh tunneling server

Tags: python, ssh, pymysql, ssh-tunnel

SSH tunnel connection is established successfully but Error connecting to RDS MySQL database via SSH tunnel: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0:52678' (10049)

same is working when I use library pymysql but not mysql.connector

can any one help me here

below is the code

```
# Create an SSH tunnel to the RDS instance via the bastion host
with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
        ssh_config['ssh_host'],
        ssh_username=ssh_config['ssh_username'],
        ssh_private_key=ssh_config['ssh_private_key'],
        remote_bind_address=(rds_config['host'], rds_config['port'])
) as tunnel:
    print("SSH tunnel created successfully")

    # Connect to the RDS instance through the SSH tunnel
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(
        user=rds_config['user'],
        password=rds_config['password'],
        host=tunnel.local_bind_host,
        port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
        database=rds_config['database']
    )
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with bastion etc, but does connection work if you'll ssh to the host and run `mysql --host host_from_rds_config --port port_from_rds_config`?

Comment: Got the solution, I had added ‘usepure’ = True